# BarTintColor does not work with PrefersLargeTitles in iOS 13 in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, bartintcolor

As I am trying to prepare our app for iOS 13, I am running into a rendering issue I can not fix.

We have code like this in our ViewDidLoad:

```
this.NavigationController.SetNavigationBarHidden(false, false);
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(3, 117, 178);
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
{
ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
};
View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;

this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.LargeTitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes
{
ForegroundColor = UIColor.White
};
```

In iOS 12, it looks like this
[image]

Just compiling for 13, it now looks like 
[image]

But if I scroll, it does look right (except for search)
[image]

We got a lot of this information previously from the dev blogs https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/go-large-ios-11/, and I tried several iterations there. I even tried putting part of this in our AppDelegate too.

I can change the text (Its actually working here, thats why you see nothing). It works fine on a page without PrefersLargeTitles set.

Comment: Hi, now xamarin maybe not fully compatible with iOS13. IOS 13 is a beta version, you can have a try when it be stable version .If there is still a problem at that time , it can be regarded as an issue.

Comment: I totally get that - but both betas are nearing their end. Beyond being a beta, looking to resolve an issue. I am not saying its an issue with the beta, I am saying I am running into this between the versions, and not sure what is going on.

Comment: Okey, although both beats are nearing the end,  everything will be ready after release version.Not only the version of IOS, but also the version of Xamarin.Forms will be ready for fitting it.

Comment: Not using Xamarin Forms here.This also works fine in a native iOS app. Submitted feedback to the project. We are making updates to our stuff so its ready at the same time as release.

Comment: Okey , if get solution will share here.

Comment: Provided an answer - this was a Xamarin bug that the developers fixed after providing a working Xcode example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in Xamarin before 12.99.3.5.

In 12.99.3.5, the new ScrollEdgeAppearance property was available, but also did not work.

This is fixed in 12.99.4.1 and later.

Progress can be tracked at https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6834